# Can I query the redis cache to get values by a list of keys?

Tags: azure, caching, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm using the azure redis cache with a .NET implementation. I have a list of keys that I need to get from the cache. Right now, this is my implementation: `

```
        List<string> planIds = ...; // already initialized.
        List<customObj> plans = new List<customObj>();  
        foreach (string currentId in planIds)
        {
            var plan = Database.StringGet(key);
            if (plan != null) plans.Add(plan);
        }
```

I've simplified it a bit for my explanation, but it works just fine. However, I was wondering if I could do a similar setup to the batch set for the batch download by passing it a list of keys that I want to retrieve. It's usually around 200+ ids. Is that doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [StringGet overloaded method](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/29b5cc180ac560b61009ec68ea20ae1d2a0052d0/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/KeyspaceIsolation/DatabaseWrapper.cs#L554)

You can pass an array of keys to get the array of values in single call.

It will execute Redis [MGET](http://redis.io/commands/mget) call [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/29b5cc180ac560b61009ec68ea20ae1d2a0052d0/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisDatabase.cs#L1456)